# Links open only on new tab or window

Tags: menus, navigation, links

I'm experiencing this strange issue on a web site just launched (www.tavoleromane.it).

There was an old thread on this and it should be related to javascript. 
Analyzing the page I don't see any error. The following are displayed:
- on Console only JQMIGRATE is installed
- on Network only style.css

Any idea? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Links open in new Tab or Window if the link `<a>` is added using `target="_blank"` (either from HTML or JavaScript).

I've just checked your site and saw only Twitter links open in new Tab / Window. Must be from the plugin you are using to generate the Twitter feed.

> *Note:* JQMIGRATE is installed by WordPress by default, it has nothing to do with links opening in new Tab / Window.

Comment: Thank you Scott. 
Problem fixed disabling all plugins and enabling again the more relevant :)